# Android Studio GUI issue in Linux

Tags: android-studio-2.0

I install Android Studio on Arch Linux.
And It have some problem.

[image: The panel seem too long compare with my computer high]

I can not create new Project because the new panel was too long.

And I can not manage to **press the button at the end of panel**.

I use `Android Studio 2.2` on `Arch Linux` with `OpenJDK8`

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Under Linux, you can move windows by pressing `Alt` and dragging the window.

Comment: It doesn't work.. cause the panel reach the top of my screen.. and I can move it above the top...

I **can't even resize the high of the panel**..

Comment: Have you actually tried to move it by dragging from a random point instead of the window bar? Can you press `Alt`, and click the center of the window, and drag?

Comment: Yes.. I tried. but the panel can't just move over the topbar... I'm using `gnome 3`